# Generate (.zip) attachment in memory (with password)

Tags: php, zip, attachment, password-protection, in-memory

Following problem:

I would like to generate an attachment with php **in memory** for a business application. The attachment has to be **password protected** as well. Afterwards Id like to send this out with an Email.

I did some research on .zip attachment with php. It seems that it is impossible with this type of attachment without using command line wrappers like exec() etc. I rather would like to avoid using a pdf (Still dont feel happy with pdf security).

Any advice how I can achieve that with some kind of package?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: attachment is a password protected container which i can encrypt. The "type" of the container doesnt matter in that case. The only importance is the encryption. Example: i  place my confidential data in a text file, then i place this text file into a container (i.e. a zip archive). Then invoke a password protection for this container. The purpose of that container is only to secure the data inside(in this example the text file). Hope this helps to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you can execute commands using 'system' function.

```
<?php 
echo system('zip -P pass file.zip file.txt'); 
?>
```

But you already mentioned that you are not interested in commands.

Here is a nice library to generate zip file: http://www.devco.net/code/zipfile.inc.txt . But It misses the ability to add password.

Another alternative is [DotnetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It supports AES Encryption with password! **But It runs only on Windows**. Am not sure which platform you use. Here is an **example code**. http://code.google.com/p/earlgrey/source/browse/trunk/vendor/DotNetZipLib-DevKit-v1.9/Examples/PHP/CreateZip-DotNetZip.php?r=571

Comment: As I mentioned this is not the solution I am looking for. I would like to avoid the command line AND the command is generating the file on harddisk, not in memory.
I am using lamp to as an enviroment. Thx anyway :).